# twitter bootsrap typeahead doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

what am I doing wrong?

Tried this in the console, and yet the typeahead doesn't work. No error.

```
→ $("#to_folder_name").typeahead({"source": DS.folders_names_array})
← [<input type=​"text" data-provide=​"typeahead" id=​"to_folder_name" size=​"15" placeholder=​"Move to..."]


→ DS.folders_names_array
← ["hhhhhhh", "dddssss", "Root", "Default", "Archive", "Custom", "1A", "after SaveExistingLocation_Test", "Hanny", "ggggg", "ggg123", "new folder", "new folder2", "dddddd", "new folder4", "ggg"]

→ $("#to_folder_name")
← [<input type=​"text" data-provide=​"typeahead" id=​"to_folder_name" size=​"15" placeholder=​"Move to...">​]
```

the typeahead.js is included.

Comment: Did you include jQuery before the typehead.js script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take away the quotes from around "source" after .typeahead( ?